# How to vectorize this multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an X matrix with shape (ni*43*91)x67 and a W tensor with shape 67x43x91. ni varies

I need to get a (ni*43*91) vector y by dotting the first ni rows of X with the first column of W to get the first ni elements of y and second ni rows of X with the second column of W to get the second ni elements of y, and so on and so forth. When I run out of columns in W, I go to the next dimension an continue.

I have two masks dim2 and dim3, both shaped (ni*43*91), in order. Right now this is what I'm doing (simplified) and it's very slow

```
for d3 in range(91):
  for d2 in range(43):
    mask = ((dim3 == d3) & (dim2 == d2))
    curr_X = X[mask, :]
    curr_W = W[:,d2,d3]
    curr_y = numpy.dot(curr_X,curr_W)
    y[mask] = curr_y
```

Is it possible to this without the for loops?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but have you looked at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html or http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html#numpy.tensordot

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what your `dim2` and `dim3` arrays are, and how is `mask` constructed, but from your description, you want something close to this:

```
ni = 10
a, b, c = 43, 91, 67
X = np.random.rand(ni*a*b, c)
W = np.random.rand(c, a, b)

X = X.reshape(ni, a*b, c)
W = W.reshape(c, a*b)

y = np.einsum('ijk, kj -> ij', X, W)
y = y.reshape(-1)
```

If you update your question with working code, i.e. a full description of `dim2` and `dim3`, we can fine tune this to return the exact same, if it doesn't already.

Comment: ni is not constant but varies. dim2 and dim3 are masks so that I can take the ni rows that correspond to the d2 and d3 dimension of W. They are like dim2 = [0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,0,0,1,2,2,3] dim3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1] n1=3 n2=2 n3=1 n4=2 ...

Comment: @bizso09 Have you tried if the code in the answer gives you the same results as your loops?

Comment: you have ni fixed as 10, so I can't compare it.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not clear, what you want to do, as your code does not work. I can only *guess* you want to do this:

```
from numpy import *
from numpy.random import rand

ni=12
A=67
B=43
C=91


X = rand(ni*B*C,A) 
W = rand(A,B,C)

y = zeros((ni*B*C))

for k in xrange(len(y)):
    b = (k/ni)/C
    c = (k/ni) % C

    #print 'y[%i] = dot(X[%i,:],W[:,%i,%i])'%(k,k,b,c)

    y[k] = dot(X[k,:],W[:,b,c])
```

If you just set `A,B,C,ni` to some lower values and uncomment the `print`-line, you will see quickly what this algorithm does.

If that is what you want, then you can do it faster with this one-liner:

```
y2 = sum(X * (W.reshape((A,B*C)).swapaxes(0,1).repeat(ni,axis=0)),axis=1)
```

Despite some index-rearrangements the crucial trick here is to use `repeat` because in the loop the indices `b,c` "freeze" for `ni` steps, while `k` grows.

I am a bit in a hurry at the moment, but if you need further explanations, just leave a comment.

Comment: ni varies, not constant. You can't declare it on top

Comment: I don't understand this, how can the number of elements in `X` "vary"? What means the formulation *an X matrix with shape (ni*43*91)x67* when `ni` "varies"?

Comment: the number of elements in X doesn't vary, only ni. if X has m rows, then divide those m rows into 43*91 blocks. The size of first block is n1 ... the size of the (43*91)th block is n(43*91). You got each block via the mask in my example.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather difficult to understand from the question what the desired result is, but the result *I think* you're after can be obtained quite easily like so:

```
y = (X.T * W[:,dim2,dim3]).sum(axis=0)
```

Comparing for correctness and speed:

```
import numpy as np

# some test data, the sorting isn't really necessary
N1, N2, N3 = 67, 43, 91
ni_avg = 1.75
N = int(ni_avg * N2 * N3)

dim2 = np.random.randint(N2, size=N)
dim3 = np.sort(np.random.randint(N3, size=N))
for d3 in range(N3):
    dim2[dim3==d3].sort()

X = np.random.rand(N, N1)
W = np.random.rand(N1, N2, N3)

# original code
def original():
    y = np.empty(X.shape[0])
    for d2 in range(W.shape[1]):
        for d3 in range(W.shape[2]):
            mask = ((dim3 == d3) & (dim2 == d2))
            curr_X = X[mask, :]
            curr_W = W[:,d2,d3]
            curr_y = numpy.dot(curr_X,curr_W)
            y[mask] = curr_y
    return y

# comparison
%timeit original()
# 1 loops, best of 3: 672 ms per loop
%timeit (X.T * W[:,dim2,dim3]).sum(axis=0)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 31.8 ms per loop
np.allclose(original(), np.sum(X.T * W[:,dim2,dim3], axis=0))
# True
```

A little faster still would be to use

```
y = np.einsum('ij,ji->i', X, W[:,dim2,dim3])
```